# Groupby .cumsum() blank if the summed column is equal to zero?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, series

I have a DataFrame .groupby() .cumsum(), with a DataFrame as follows:

```
   Col_A Col_B Col_C
 1   A    0            
 2   A    1     1      
 3   A    1     2      
 4   A    1     3      
 5   B    0     0      
 6   B    1     1      
 7   B    0            
 8   B    1     2      
 9   C    1     1      
10   C    1     2      
11   C    1     3      
12   C    0
```

The sum of Col_B is `df.groupby(['Col_A'])['Col_B'].cumsum()`. However, when Col_B == 0, the .cumsum() is blank. How do I record the `.cumsum()` even when Col_B is blank?

The resulting DataFrame should resemble:

```
      Col_A Col_B Col_C
     1   A    0     0       
     2   A    1     1      
     3   A    1     2      
     4   A    1     3      
     5   B    0     0      
     6   B    1     1      
     7   B    0     1       
     8   B    1     2      
     9   C    1     1      
    10   C    1     2      
    11   C    1     3      
    12   C    0     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need first filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df['Col_C'] = df[df['Col_B'] != 0].groupby(['Col_A'])['Col_B'].cumsum()
print (df)
   Col_A  Col_B  Col_C
1      A      0    NaN
2      A      1    1.0
3      A      1    2.0
4      A      1    3.0
5      B      0    NaN
6      B      1    1.0
7      B      0    NaN
8      B      1    2.0
9      C      1    1.0
10     C      1    2.0
11     C      1    3.0
12     C      0    NaN
```

Or:

```
df['Col_C'] = df.query('Col_B != 0').groupby(['Col_A'])['Col_B'].cumsum()
print (df)
   Col_A  Col_B  Col_C
1      A      0    NaN
2      A      1    1.0
3      A      1    2.0
4      A      1    3.0
5      B      0    NaN
6      B      1    1.0
7      B      0    NaN
8      B      1    2.0
9      C      1    1.0
10     C      1    2.0
11     C      1    3.0
12     C      0    NaN
```

And last replace `NaN`s by `ffill` ([`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with method='ffill'). But get first values still `NaN`s, which are replaced by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and last convert column to `int`:

```
df['Col_C']  = df['Col_C'].ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   Col_A  Col_B  Col_C
1      A      0      0
2      A      1      1
3      A      1      2
4      A      1      3
5      B      0      3
6      B      1      1
7      B      0      1
8      B      1      2
9      C      1      1
10     C      1      2
11     C      1      3
12     C      0      3
```

Comment: This solution is correct as implemented. I had an idea that .ffill() after .groupby() was probably correct, and it was. Thanks!

Comment: Glad can help, nice weekend!

Answer (score 2):

Having a column of 0s is not the same as having a completely blank column.
If you have NAs in a column the .cumsum() for that column should in fact be NA(or 'blank' as you say).
You could check to see if the whole column is NA and set the value accordingly.

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
DataFrame.cumsum(axis=None, skipna=True, *args, **kwargs)
Return cumulative sum over requested axis.

skipna : boolean, default True
Exclude NA/null values. If an entire row/column is NA, the result will be NA
```